# How to load components from child path by default on Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have a child route path in my @NgModule defined as:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'orders',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    component: ListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'view/:id',
        component: ViewOrderComponent
      },
    ]
  }
]),
```

The problem i have is that when i load in the browser the page /orders loads fine, when i navigate to /orders/view/100 still works, but if i refresh the browser(with the url /orders/view/100) it loads but goes to /orders, it doesnt load /orders/view/100 as expected, i now is loading the page /orders/view/100 because i can see in the Chrome dev tools, but after loading it goes to /orders.

How can i make that after loading the route orders it also loads the route orders/view?

Comment: terrible mistake: looks like i had a this.router.navigate(['/orders']); that was causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this. On your second path definition make it an absolute path, "/orders"

Comment: looks like is not a valid configuration : "Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route '/orders': path cannot start with a slash"